# zabbix regex trigger on multiple string values

Tags: zabbix

I have the following trigger the gist is I only want it to trigger when it's already a problem and when any of the expected values are not found.

Currently this is not working.  Any suggestions?

```
({TRIGGER.VALUE}=1 and {Template_App_JAMS_Agent:app.jams.agent.state.regexp(Online|Connected|Connecting|Idle|Throttled)}=0)
```

edit - I know it's not working as currently I have a value of Timeout to one of those keys for hours and it's not triggering.  The regex does not seem to be working.

Comment: sorry, you want this trigger to be a problem "when it's already a problem"? can't you just use `.diff()` instead of `regexp()`?

Comment: I don't want the trigger to fire unless it's already a problem hence the `{TRIGGER.VALUE}=1` but unfortunately the `regexp()` doesn't seem to be registering as far as I can tell so it's never getting registered as a problem.

Comment: the regex is fine, it's TRIGGER.VALUE to always be 0, you can't use it like that

Comment: omg I was typing a reply and started laughing it's so obvious you're right.  the trigger is never going to fire because it's never going to fire first to be able to fire again.  lol.